# Do Too Many Electrolytes Make You Fat

Tags: weight-loss, diet, weight-gain, electrolytes, sodium

I've been consuming electrolytes before and after sports disolved into water **without sugar**.

Can electrolytes in high volume make you gain weight?

Comment: How do so many upvote this without any close flags? It's pretty much straight nutrition advice.

Comment: The electrolyte drinks are sold to people to replenish workouts.  Maybe just rephrase the question - "Can the no/low calorie electrolyte sports drinks I digest after working out make me fat?"

Comment: Additionally, electrolytes really have no calories. All calories in sports drinks come from some form of sugar, usually maltodextrin or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are drinking flavored salt water.  If it has no calories it can't make you fat but it can make you feel bloated.

http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/sodium/NU00284

Mayo clinic references too much sodium can lead to water retention.  So maybe in the short term it could make you retain a percent of an ounce of water in your system.  Not fat but maybe feeling fat and maybe weighing (slightly) more on a scale the next day.

Comment: Yep.  To be clear, it increases weight but not fat.

Comment: Well the actual weight gain is... it depends.  If your body is already storing a lot of water weight it will be null or very minimal.  Also an active person will sweat out a ton of salt.  Drinking 16 ounces of water will make you gain 16 ounces.  I know we are talking semantics but I do not count water weight as weight.  If you sit in a sauna for an hour to drop 5 pounds, fitness-wise you have lost no weight.

Comment: The average gym goer usually considers gaining and losing weight as movement on the scale.  While water weight is only of real concern to athletes who have to make a weight class, too many people only use a scale to measure progress and don't consider where the weight gain or loss is from.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I believe you are 100% correct.  But it is the informed job to dispel those myths/issues.  If you drink less water to lose weight then your body will automatically try to store more water when it gets hydrated.

Comment: And speaking from experience - I had to make weight for years when boxing.  I drank a minimum of 200 ounces of fluids a day.  The only time we drank less was 1 day before weigh-ins if we were close to not making weight.

Comment: Yep, same thing for us power lifters.  In fact we learned from boxers and wrestlers.  But, if we continue this any more I guess we should take it to chat.  We are definitely in agreement.